# How to parse json of an incoming POST request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, http-post

I have the following problem. A web service is sending a JSON POST request to my app and I want to parse it.

I thought I just can access the params with

```
@var = params[:name_of_the_JSON_fields]
```

but it doesn't work. I see in my Heroku logs, that the request is done and that the parameters are there, but I just can't store them.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 30):

When you post JSON (or XML), rails will handle all of the parsing for you, but you need to include the correct headers.

Have your app include:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

And all will be cool.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it. Can you be a bit more specific? I don't want to post JSON. A web service is accessing my app with a POST request and I just want to get the data from this request and then parse it.

Comment: @thomas8877 it's not being parsed because the web service is not using the correct content-type. If you can't make it use "application/json" then you'll have to associate another content-type as json so Rails will understand it needs to parse it.

Comment: thanks guys! I have to learn more about this web service stuff, because at the moment it is just too complicated.

Comment: This is the best solution when the author controls source of the request. However, this solution is not possible for many cases (where your app is receiving a request from an external service, such as Amazon SNS for instance). In those cases, see my answer.

Answer (score 19):

In most cases with the symptom desribed, the true root of the problem is the source of the incoming request: if it is sending JSON to your app, it should be sending a Content-Type header of `application/json`.

If you're able to modify the app sending the request, adjust that header, and Rails will parse the body as JSON, and everything will work as expected, with the parsed JSON fields appearing in your `params` hash.

When that is not possible (for instance when you don't control the source of the request - as in the case of receiving an Amazon SNS notification), Rails will not automatically parse the body as JSON for you, so the best you can to is read and parse it yourself, as in:

```rb
json_params = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks:  ""the true root of the problem is the source of the incoming request: if it is sending JSON to your app, it should be sending a Content-Type header of application/json""

Comment: "Amazon SNS notification" — that was me, thank you!

Answer (score 17):

This answer may not be particular to this exact question, but I had a similar issue when setting up AWS SNS push notifications. I was unable to parse or even view the initial subscription request. Hopefully this helps someone else with a similar problem.

I found that you don't need to parse if you have a simple API setup with default format set to json, similar to below (in config/routes.rb):

```
 namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json}  do
    namespace :v1 do
      post "/controller_name" => 'controller_name#create'
      get "/controller_name" => 'controller_name#index'
    end
  end
```

The important thing I discovered is that the incoming post request comes is accessible by the variable `request`.  In order to convert this into readable JSON format, you can call the following:

```
request.body.read()
```

Comment: Definitely right path here when working with AWS SNS, I ended up needing 
`result = JSON.parse(request.body.string)`
`message = JSON.parse(result["Message"])`

Answer (score 10):

If you are receiving JSON in the params hash you can convert it yourself:

```
@var = JSON.parse(params[:name_of_the_JSON_fields])
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably too late to help you, but perhaps future people will check here :)  Perhaps rails is supposed to parse json for you, but that's never worked for me.  I read the request body directly.  I use the 'Yajl' json parser - it is very fast.  But regular old 'json' will work here too (just use JSON.parse)

```
request.body.rewind
body = Yajl::Parser.parse request.body.read.html_safe
```

Comment: This is not a really good solution..
Because request.body returns a StringIO whose charset is set to Encoding::BINARY.
So if you pass a non ascii character, it will raise an encoding exception

Comment: Shouldn't binary encoding be able to handle any type of character?

Comment: Nope, it will use ASCII-8Bit, and try to format it to utf8.. don't know why

Comment: Setting proper `Content-Type` as first answer suggests does make rails parse it by itself. Not sure why you see what you see.