# Type error for implicit conversion while working with API and JSON data in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I making a post request through postman with the following JSON code:

```
 {
 "order":
 { 
    "txnid":"SA", 
    "stamp_amount": "200", 
    "service": {
                    "name": "Affidavit"
                }, 
    "payment": {
                "created_at": {
                                "strftime": "12-6-2016"
                              }, 
                "mode": "Cash"
                },
    "user": {
                "profile": {
                                "first_name": "Mahesh", 
                                "country": {
                                                "phone_code":"080"
                                            }
                            }, 
                "phone":"9988998899"
            }, 
    "address":{
                    "address1":"dadacsa",
                    "address2":"ca", 
                    "locality":{
                                    "name":"asca"
                                }, 
                    "landmark":"asca", 
                    "city":{
                                "name":"aacs", "state":{
                                                            "name":"asca"
                                                        }
                            }
                }, 
    "product":"asx", 
    "total_amount":"5000", 
    "document":{
                    "default_price":"100"
                }, 
    "delivery_amount":"99", 
    "discount":"0"
    }, 
 "no_of_copies":"1"
 }
```

As I make request to my invoice_api_controller with the following:

```
 def order_invoice
        response = Hash.new
        result = Hash.new
        if params[:order] && params[:order][:txnid] && params[:no_of_copies] && params[:order][:total_amount]!= 0
            @order = JSON.parse(params[:order]).each do |order|
                @order['stamp_amount'] = order['stamp_amount'] || ''
                @order['txnid'] = order['txnid']
                @order['service']['name'] = order['service']['name'] || ''
                @order['payment']['created_at']['strftime'] = order['payment']
                ['created_at']['strftime']
                @order['payment']['mode'] = order['payment']['mode'] || ''
                @order['user']['name'] = order['user']['name']
                @order['user']['profile']['first_name'] = order['user']
                ['profile']['first_name'] || ''
                @order['address']['address1'] = order['address']['address1'] 
                || '' 
                @order['address']['address2'] = order['address']['address2'] 
                || ''
                @order['address']['locality']['name'] = order['address']
                ['locality']['name'] || ''
                @order['address']['landmark'] = order['address']['landmark'] 
                || ''
                @order['address']['city']['name'] = order['address']['city']
                ['name'] || '' 
                @order['address']['city']['state']['name'] = order['address']
                ['city']['state']['name'] || ''
                @order['user']['profile']['country']['phone_code'] = ['user']
                ['profile']['country']['phone_code'] || ''
                @order['user']['phone'] = order['user']['phone'] || ''
                @order['product'] = order['product'] || ''
                @order['total_amount'] = order['total_amount']
                @order['document']['default_price'] = order['document']
                ['default_price'] || ''
                @order['delivery_amount'] =  order['delivery_amount'] || ''
                @order['discount'] =  order['discount'] || ''
                @no_of_copies = params[:no_of_copies]
            end
            response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK
        else
            response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
        end 
        render :json => response
    end
```

It throws the following error 
**no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String**
 for the line **@order = JSON.parse(params[:order]).each do |order|**

I am not sure what am I doing wrong for I am new to working with Rails and APi's.Please help with detailed elaboration.It would help a great deal

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
Content-Type = 'application/json'
```

in postman

You may look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587186/how-to-build-postman-request-for-rails-post-method) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4360178/3292174)

After that you don't need to parse params, all parsing done by Rails. You just get `params[:order]`